# Sklearn method in class

Tags: python-3.x, oop, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I would like to create a class that uses `sklearn` transformation methods. I found this [article](https://dreisbach.us/articles/building-scikit-learn-compatible-transformers/) and I am using it as an example.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin

def minmax(dataframe):
  minmax_transformer = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
  return minmax_tranformer


class FunctionFeaturizer(TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, scaler):
        self.scaler = scaler

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        fv = self.scaler(X)
        return  fv

if __name__=="__main__":
     scaling = FunctionFeaturizer(minmax)
     df = pd.DataFrame({'feature': np.arange(10)})
     df_scaled = scaling.fit(df).transform(df)
     print(df_scaled)
```

The output is `StandardScaler(copy=True, with_mean=True, with_std=True)` which is actually the result of the `preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(df)` if I use it out of the class.

What I am expecting is:

```
array([[0.        ],
       [0.11111111],
       [0.22222222],
       [0.33333333],
       [0.44444444],
       [0.55555556],
       [0.66666667],
       [0.77777778],
       [0.88888889],
       [1.        ]])
```

I am feeling that I am mixing few things here but I do not know what.

**Update**
I did some modifications:

```
def minmax():
    return preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()

class FunctionFeaturizer(TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, scaler):
        self.scaler = scaler

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def fit_transform(self, X):
        self.scaler.fit(X)
        return self.scaler.transform(X)

if __name__=="__main__":
    scaling = FunctionFeaturizer(minmax)
    df = pd.DataFrame({'feature': np.arange(10)})
    df_scaled = scaling.fit_transform(df)
    print(df_scaled)
```

But now I am receiving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/my_file.py", line 33, in <module>
    test_scale = scaling.fit_transform(df)
  File "C:/my_file.py", line 26, in fit_transform
    self.scaler.fit(X)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'fit'
```

Comment: First, you are not using the scaler in the your `fit()`. Second, you are not using the `scaler().transform()` in your `transform()`.

Comment: @VivekKumar Thanks for the reply. Can you please enlight me a little bit more?

Comment: From the `transform()` you are returning `self.scaler(X)`, which equals `minmax(X)`, but the function `minmax` dont use the input (`X` or `dataframe`) anywhere, and returns the MinMaxScaler. Thats what you are getting.

Comment: Can anyone help me on that?

Comment: @DimKoim did the answer below help you?

Comment: @BrunoGL at one part but it does not answer my main question. Thanks for helping me out tho.

Comment: @DimKoim, I read your question again. However, there is no question there...

Comment: @BrunoGL Please have a look at the expected output.

Comment: @DimKoim check my answer again, I edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solving your error

in your code you have:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    scaling = FunctionFeaturizer(minmax)
    df = pd.DataFrame({'feature': np.arange(10)})
    df_scaled = scaling.fit_transform(df)
    print(df_scaled)
```

change the line

```
scaling = FunctionFeaturizer(minmax)
```

to

```
scaling = FunctionFeaturizer(minmax())
```

you need to call the function to get the instantiation of MinMaxScaler returned to you.

## Suggestion

Instead of implementing `fit` and `fit_transform`, implement `fit` and `transform` unless you can optimize both process into `fit_tranform`. This way, it is clearer what you are doing.

If you implement only `fit` and `transform`, you can still call `fit_transform` because you extend the `TransformerMixin` class. It will just call both functions in a row.

## Getting your expected results

Your transformer is looking at every column of your dataset and distributing the values linearly between `0` and `1`.

So, to get your expected results, it will really depend on what your `df` looks like. However, you did not share that with us, so it is difficult to tell if you will get it.

However, if you have `df = [[0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9]]`, you will see your expected result.

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    scaling = FunctionFeaturizer(minmax())
    df = [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]]
    df_scaled = scaling.fit_transform(df)
    print(df_scaled)

> [[0.        ]
>  [0.11111111]
>  [0.22222222]
>  [0.33333333]
>  [0.44444444]
>  [0.55555556]
>  [0.66666667]
>  [0.77777778]
>  [0.88888889]
>  [1.        ]]
```